# JWT (JSON Web Token) in PHP without using 3rd-party library. How to sign?

Tags: php, json, authentication, jwt, sha

There are a few libraries for implementing JSON Web Tokens (JWT) in PHP, such as [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt).  I am writing my own, very small and simple class but cannot figure out why my signature fails validation [here](http://jwt.io/) even though I've tried to stick to the standard.  I've been trying for hours and I'm stuck. Please help!

My code is simple

```
//build the headers
$headers = ['alg'=>'HS256','typ'=>'JWT'];
$headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));

//build the payload
$payload = ['sub'=>'1234567890','name'=>'John Doe', 'admin'=>true];
$payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));

//build the signature
$key = 'secret';
$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256',"$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded",$key);

//build and return the token
$token = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature";
echo $token;
```

The `base64url_encode` function:

```
function base64url_encode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

My headers and payload perfectly match the [validation site's](http://jwt.io/) default JWT, but my signature doesn't match so my token is flagged as invalid.  This standard seems really straightforward so what's wrong with my signature?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I solved it!  I did not realize that the signature itself needs to be base64 encoded. In addition, I needed to set the last optional parameter of the `hash_hmac` function to `$raw_output=true` (see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).  In short I needed to change my code from the original:

```
//build the signature
$key = 'secret';
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256',"$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded",$key);

//build and return the token
$token = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature";
```

To the corrected:

```
//build the signature
$key = 'secret';
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256',"$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded",$key,true);
$signature_encoded = base64url_encode($signature);

//build and return the token
$token = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
echo $token;
```

Comment: Does this work across networks, and different URLs...?
generating this token on HTTP server and verifying on HTTPS server. its failing every time..

Answer (score 11):

If you want to solve it using **RS256** (instead of HS256 like OP) you can use it like this:

```php
//build the headers
$headers = ['alg'=>'RS256','typ'=>'JWT'];
$headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));

//build the payload
$payload = ['sub'=>'1234567890','name'=>'John Doe', 'admin'=>true];
$payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));

//build the signature
$key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ....";
openssl_sign("$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded", $signature, $key, 'sha256WithRSAEncryption'); 
$signature_encoded = base64url_encode($signature);

//build and return the token
$token = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
echo $token;
```

Took me way longer than I'd like to admit

Comment: Solved my issue using "openssl_sign()". When i am trying to Signed using hash_hmac not able to descrypt key value properly. But now solved with using base64url_encode & openssl_sign. Thanks @Christian

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/gradus0/appleAuth
look method $appleAuthObj->get_jwt_token()

```
<?php
include_once "appleAuth.class.php";

// https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list/serviceId -- indificator value
$clientId = ""; // com.youdomen
// your developer account id -> https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/
$teamId = "";
// key value show in -> https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list
$key = ""; 
// your page url where this script
$redirect_uri = ""; // example: youdomen.com/appleAuth.class.php
// path your key file, download file this -> https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list
$keyPath =''; // example: ./AuthKey_key.p8 

try{    
    $appleAuthObj = new \appleAuth\sign($clientId,$teamId,$key,$redirect_uri,$keyPath); 
    
    if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
        $jwt_token = $appleAuthObj->get_jwt_token($_REQUEST['code']);
        $response = $appleAuthObj->get_response($_REQUEST['code'],$jwt_token);
        $result_token = $this->read_id_token($response['read_id_token']);

        var_dump($response);
        var_dump($result_token);
    }else{
        $state = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
        echo "<a href='".$appleAuthObj->get_url($state)."'>sign</a>";
    }
                                                                                    
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).