# Reverse JWT in PHP

Tags: php, api, security

I had created JWT in php.I had found the way to create JWT from following link.

[JWT (JSON Web Token) in PHP without using 3rd-party library. How to sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773477/jwt-json-web-token-in-php-without-using-3rd-party-library-how-to-sign)

```
<?php
//build the headers
$headers = ['alg'=>'HS256','typ'=>'JWT'];
$headers_encoded = base64_encode(json_encode($headers));

//build the payload
$payload = ['sub'=>'1234567890','name'=>'John Doe', 'admin'=>true];
$payload_encoded = base64_encode(json_encode($payload));

//build the signature
$key = 'secret';
$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256',"$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded",$key,true);
$signature_encoded = base64_encode($signature);

//build and return the token
$token = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
echo $token;
?>
```

Now how can i authenticate it. I am sending token from Android but i want to validate that this is proper token or not. So how can i do it in code before fulfilling the request.

Should i store token in database?

And is it proper way to give security to api?

Comment: Use a library. https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt

Comment: I know there are library available but i want to do it manually. I think if jwt token generate is possible then reversing it also possible. Https://jwt.io can do this task.

Comment: "I want to do it manually" -> http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a well known JWT library for this. This is cryptography, and rolling your own crypto is usually dangerous. There are a few packages around with widespread adoption that have been vetted by security professionals.

If you *are* going to do this manually, at least take inspiration from one of these packages to ensure that you're doing it correctly: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/src/JWT.php#L69-L138

The linked code is pretty easy to follow. Essentially you're:

1. Decoding the token by splitting on `.`, `base64_decode`ing, and then `json_decode`ing.
2. Checking the signature of the provided JWT against one that is computed again from the decoded header and payload. The `alg` header property in your example will tell you what algorithm to use to check the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution for your example :

```
    public function verify(string $token, string $secret): bool
    {
        [$headerEncoded, $bodyEncoded, $signatureEncoded] = explode('.', $token);
        $signature = base64_decode($signatureEncoded);

        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', implode('.', [$headerEncoded, $bodyEncoded]), $secret, true);

        return \hash_equals($signature, $hash);
    }
```

But you sohuld encode and decode string with [URL-Safe Base64](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/v5.2.0/src/JWT.php#L333-L353).