# Issue with validating jwt

Tags: php, json, jwt

I'm experimenting with `jwt`'s and I made a really simple one in `php` and went to the jwt.io debugger to validate it, and the header and payload were decoded correctly, but it said that the signature was unverified. I looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773477/jwt-json-web-token-in-php-without-using-3rd-party-library-how-to-sign) and [copied this article's code exactly](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/security/using-a-json-web-token-in-php.html) and wasn't able to validate with any secret key. I tried changing the string I set my secret key, selecting and deselecting the box and I couldn't get anything to validate. Here is my code:

```
$key = "mySecret";
$header = ["typ"=>"JWT","alg"=>"HS256"];
$header = base64_encode(json_encode($header));     
$payload = ["valid"=>"true","isAdmin"=>"false"];
$payload = base64_encode(json_encode($payload));
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256','$header.$payload', $key, true);
$signature = base64_encode($signature);
$token = "$header.$payload.$signature";
echo $token;
```

What step did I miss?

### EDIT TO INCLUDE `JWT`

---

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2YWxpZCI6InRydWUiLCJpc0FkbWluIjoiZmFsc2UifQ==.QzjPt33UOjEPdPLtyhvs4DYrAD2TnQgv8P0WuHXuj/c=

Comment: could you post a sample token?

Comment: @pedrofb edited to include above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you linked is incorrect. The header and payload are base64 encoded but it should be **base64 urlencoded**. See [RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-6)

> A JWT is represented as a sequence of URL-safe parts separated by
> period ('.') characters.  Each part contains a base64url-encoded
> value.

Try adding this function provided as comment in `base64_encode` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php). Note that the SO question is also using it

```
function base64url_encode($data) { 
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
} 

$header = base64url_encode(json_encode($header));  
$payload = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));  
$signature = base64url_encode($signature);
```

Comment: Thank you! It was two issues then...that was definitely a big one, and also, when hashing the `$header.$payload` into the signature, I used single quotes instead of double, so I changed them to double, combined with the base64url_encode, and it worked!