# Laravel 8 JWT with Login Page

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-8

```php
public function login(Request $request) 
{
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    $data = [
        'email' => $email, 
        'password' => $password, 
    ];

    // I want to create jwt token for the above code
}
```

I want to create jwt token only for the above data using web.php route

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT (JSON Web Token) in PHP without using 3rd-party library. How to sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773477/jwt-json-web-token-in-php-without-using-3rd-party-library-how-to-sign)

Comment: Will this jwt package will work for laravel 8 with xampp . Right now I am using jwt-auth by tymon

Comment: Thank you @Osama Bin Saleem it worked I just change my jwt to Firebase/jwt

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: My Question was to create JWT token in PHP using tymon/jwt-auth but i was having problem with that jwt library so i changed to firebase/php-jwt with which I was comfortable using it with laravel 8 so can you tell me is it correct to use it with laravel 8

Comment: @Nico Haase  can you tell me how to implement tymon/jwt-auth library using laravel 8 and xampp as I am new to this technology.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing. This should also include your attempts to resolve the problem